# Defining a Query with Multiple Values

Tags: sql, query

I have been trying by best to create a definition query which would select a group of municipalities from among the many in my state.  I have tried commands of all sorts of variations from "Name"='Chatham'AND 'Chester' AND 'Far Hills'..... to "Name"=('Chatham', 'Chester', 'Far Hills... and so on but I keep getting an error when I try to validate.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 28):

[Building a query expression](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Building_a_query_expression/00s50000002t000000/). Check the Combining Expressions sub-heading to see how to use the AND/OR operators correctly.

For your example you should implement "IN":

"Name" IN ('Chatham','Chester')

Comment: Great! For me single quote was the gotcha.

Answer (score 15):

Use "Name" IN ('Chatham','Chester Falls'...) 
Separate each with a comma and end with a closed parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

I would think OR rather than AND

Comment: @Katie, in your example, you also left out the fieldname in front of each query attribute.  If you wanted to use this mething, you would need to include the fieldname in front of each query attribute: "Name"='Chatham' OR "Name"='Chester' OR "Name"='Far Hills'.  This is slow and tedious, so using the "IN" operator is much more efficient.